# Why do people call cancer the machalah?

Tags: words, choleh-sick

It seems that people use the word machalah to refer to cancer not only as a translation of the word (although there might be a more specific and correct translation) but because they do not want to say that someone has cancer. Why do people do this?

Comment: I've never noticed this.

Comment: I'm not sure what community you live in but in Anglo-Charedi communities in Israel it seems fairly common.

Comment: Maybe you should say that in the question...

Comment: @DoubleAA - In Chassidic / Yeshiva communities it is basically a universal convention to refer to cancer as "the machlah" (the disease) or "yenna machlah" (*that* disease). Even when writing in English, they will often call it "the dreaded disease" rather than use the c-word.

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20080509162804/http://www.math.wustl.edu/~msh210/torah_vayera.html

Comment: @msh210 - this goes beyond "al tiftach"; people won't say the word even when referring to someone who's already ill, or even in innocent contexts.

Comment: @Dave Like the [Tropic of Machalah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropic_of_Cancer)?

Comment: @DoubleAA - you know what I mean... I think...

Comment: @Dave, "even when referring to someone who's already ill": like the woman in the _haftara_.

Comment: @msh210 - if they were following her example, they wouldn't talk about the illness at all, even using generic terms.

Comment: The Hebrew Wikipedia article on [Israeli] Haredi slang mentions the Hebrew version of this: http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%92%D7%94_%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%93%D7%99%D7%AA#.D7.9E.D7.95.D7.98.D7.99.D7.91.D7.99.D7.9D_.D7.A0.D7.95.D7.A1.D7.A4.D7.99.D7.9D

Comment: Contrast with a popular yiddish pejorative, "Chalera": http://www.jewish-languages.org/jewish-english-lexicon/words/1368

Comment: This seems like Jews not Judaism.

Answer (score 3):

The [Gemara](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=112b&format=text) refers to Tzaraas as "Davar Acher" - "lit. Something else".

Comment: I see that this could be a source. Any explanation as to why the gemara does that?

Answer (score 2):

Satmar rov reb yoel said if you call it that then it will hopefully dissapear

Comment: citing a source would greatly improve your answer

Comment: Why would calling it "the disease" make it disappear? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Dave if I knew the name of every person I passed on the street then I (maybe nefesh or ruach) would be more consumed with the attention; but not knowing their names, I can allow the crowd to pass by.

Comment: @NewAlexandria - not sure I understand the analogy. But if it's true, why shouldn't the same apply regarding, say, Alzheimer's or Parkinson's or MS etc.?

Comment: Alzheimers and Parkinsons can't disappear

Comment: @NewAlexandria מי שם פה לאדם? If you are relying on God's help then I don't see the difference.

Comment: I wonder that Satmar rov reb yoel is saying the choice of words here is not a minhag, but that to use the name of thing thus עֲשִׂיתֶֽם, but maybe if you don't **use** the name then it is like a prayer that Hashem may עָשָׂ֔הוּ otherwise.

Comment: Has anyone found the source for this?